# Generating Images from image styles in drupal 7

Tags: 7, caching, media

I'm just getting accustomed to the changes in drupal 7, I've created a number of nodes that have an image field. The nodes were created as dummy content from the Devel module. I then created a view, added a number of fields, and chose my image style as a formatted for one of the fields. The only thing I can't figure out is how to get Drupal to generate the the images, I tried re-generating the dummy conent, but it still does not create the thumbnails.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the folders where the images go writable? Also check the tmp folder

Comment: yup, was a permissions thing

Answer (score 0):

image style images should be dynamically generated as needed.  Are the links to the images being formed properly?  They should be in the files/styles folder